# What is more effective for dismissing data on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Basic question but when it comes to disregarding data points on SQL, which of the two codes would work best to NOT include customers living in a city beginning with A, or are they interchangeable? code below;

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CITY LIKE '[B-Z]%'
;

OR

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City NOT LIKE 'A%'
;

Comment: What have you tried to gather an answer? Where are you stuck?

Comment: These do not do the same thing.  In fact, I don't know of any cities whose name starts with `[`, but you might have a special database.

Comment: What do you think is better: (a) writing code that does what you mean, or (b) writing code that avoids doing something that in some cases is the opposite of what you mean...?

Answer (score 1):

First, these are not equivalent.  MySQL does not support character classes in `LIKE`.  And no city name starts with `[`.

Even in databases that do (i.e. SQL Server), both are probably going to do a full table scan, simply because the queries are selecting almost all rows.  However, the second has the possibility of using an index on `City` because the first character in the `LIKE` pattern is not a wildcard.  Hence, the second would be preferred, in a database were the two were functionally equivalent.